# Async task returning a value to activity after its destroyed

Tags: android, android-intent, asynchronous

In android, I have an activity A and activity B. Activity A is my home screen, and from there I navigate to activity B. Activity B spawns off an async task to make network calls, and when the task returns, it calls a method in activity B to update the value of some variable.

Now the problem is, when I press the back or up button to go back from B to A **before** the async task returns, I get a null pointer exception. My thinking is that the activity B is destroyed when back is pressed, so the program can't find the variable to update.

How do I deal with this? I've tried using broadcast calls, so activity B would register for a broadcast that is called by the async task when it returns. This does solve the problem, but introduces another one -- when I put the phone to sleep by doing a quick press of the power button, no broadcast gets received since I have to unregister broadcasts during onPause of activity B.

How would you solve this problem? How do I deal with returning an async task's result to an activity that may be destroyed at any time?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Use a Service to run your Task or IntentService. It will reduce the pain.

Comment: Use AsyncTask implementation from https://github.com/rfqu/df4android - it survives Activity recreations.